# Recursive Definition of a Series

Tags: summation, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have a series such as the one below:

\begin{equation}
2^n(\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n+1}i)\text{ for all $n \geq 1$}
\end{equation}

I need to write a recursive definition for it. Here's what I have so far:

\begin{equation}
  sum(n)=\begin{cases}
    n, & \text{if $n<1$}.\\
    recurse, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I'm not entirely sure what the recursive step would be or if the return for a value less than 1 should be n. Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I think it means $sum(0)=0$, $sum(n\geq1)=2^n\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i=2sum(n-1)+2^n\cdot(n+1)$.

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
sum(0)&=0\\
sum(n\geq1)&=2^n\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i \\ 
&=2\cdot\left(2^{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^{n}i\right)+2^n\cdot(n+1)\\
&=2\cdot sum(n-1)+2^n\cdot(n+1)
\end{align}$$

Or,
\begin{equation}
  sum(n)=\begin{cases}
    n, & \text{if $n<1$}.\\
    2\cdot sum(n-1)+2^n\cdot(n+1), & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Could you by chance put it in the form I started with? I'm having a hard time following what you wrote.

Comment: I edited your post a bit for readability. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks.

Comment: @Nic And I also added your style too. Is it better now?

Comment: @Nic Using the recursive definition, $S(0)=0$, $S(1)=2\cdot0+2^1\cdot(1+1)=2\cdot2=4$, $S(2)=2\cdot4+2^2\cdot(2+1)=8+4\cdot3=20$.

Comment: @KayK. Can you explain how you got the $4$ in $S(2)=2*4...$?

Comment: @Nic $S(2)=2\cdot S(1)+2^2\cdot(2+1)=2\cdot4+2^2\cdot(2+1)$.

Comment: @KayK. Thanks!!